# transform JavapairRDD to dataframe using scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, java-pair-rdd, geospark

I have a javapairRDD in below format

```
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD[com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry,com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry]
```

Key is a polygon and value is a point in the polygon

eg:

```
[(polygon(1,2,3,4), POINT (-80.0140735758427 40.43926684782609) )]
```

How to I transform this `javapairRDD` to `Dataframe` with three columns ?

`df: String, double, double`

Here my first column will be a polygon, second column as longitude and third column as latitude

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below solution worked

javapairrddvariable.rdd.toDF()